# Question About Orientation and Surface Level Integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I'm stuck on this question: Let S be a level surface defined by f (x, y, z) = k where k is a constant.
Show that the two possible orientations of S can be chosen as ± ∇f / ‖∇f ‖

I believe in order to prove this I need to use the dot product, but I am not sure which vectors to include in the dot product calculation. Any help and suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Haven’t you shown in class (or the text) that $\nabla f$ is normal to a level surface of $f$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes we have, but I'm not sure how to show this mathematically.

Comment: The book should certainly have done this. Given any vector $\vec v$ tangent to the surface at $p$, what is the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in direction $\vec v$?

Comment: @TedShifrin What would the direction v be in this case? The surface p would be f(x, y, z) but what would v be?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site. Specifically, you can get double norm bars using `\|`.